# What was the relative velocity of Cosmos 2221 and TIMED?

Tags: debris, kessler-syndrome

[According to Space.com](https://www.space.com/near-collision-nasa-timed-satellite-russian-space-junk), on the 28th of February at 06:34 UTC, the dead Russian spy satellite Cosmos 2221 and the NASA spacecraft *TIMED*, which are both orbiting at an altitude of about 608 kilometres, passed each other at a distance of less than 20 metres.

Obviously space junk is a problem and a collison would have created a lot of debris.  Do we know enough about the orbital parameters of these two objects to determine their relative velocity at the closest point?

Answer (score 5):

[14.085 km/s](https://twitter.com/LeoLabs_Space/status/1762851748702511418) as calculated by LeoLabs.

Comment: +1  That's 50,706 kph and (depending on the altitude) the orbital velocity at LEO is around 28,000 kph.  The image posted on Twitter looks like they are in quite different orbits though, which might account for the high speed.

Comment: @DaveGremlin ya Kosmos 2221 and TIMED are at about  82.5° and 74.1° respectively. $\cos(82.5-74.1)$ is 0.99 so they can do anything between "gently graze" and hit near-head-on.